# How to remove line segments for pie chart. Kendo Pie Chart React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, pie-chart

I'm trying to remove these line segments that appear between the slices value and the slice of the pie itself.

[image]

```
 <Chart transitions={false} style={{ height: '100%', width: '50%' }}>
                    <ChartLegend visible={false} />
                    <ChartTitle text={resource.Occupied} />
                    <ChartSeries>
                        <ChartSeriesItem
                            labels={{
                                visible: true,
                                align: 'center',
                                distance: 10,
                            }}
                            type='pie'
                            tooltip={{
                                visible: true,
                            }}
                            data={data}
                            categoryField='Field'
                            field='Value'
                        />
                    </ChartSeries>
                </Chart>
```

I've ran through the docs and can't seem to find a simple solution to keep the numbers next to the slice of pie but remove the line segments.

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [series.connectors.width](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.connectors#series.connectors.width) to 0

e.g.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
    type: "pie",
    labels: {
      visible: true,
      position: "outsideEnd",
    },
    connectors: {
      width: 0,
    },
    data: [1 , 2]
  }]
});
```

for react: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/api/LabelConnectors/

Comment: You're a boss. Thank you for this. I would've assumed the connectors were a field of type labels.